# "Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers." problems with 1 pc

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

We a using Google Maps Api on a school project. I get the error message "Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers."

The strange thing it's only on my copy of the app. If i build/run the app on another PC it works - but not on mine.  (We use the same code).

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix this? Yes I have used Google, and StackOverFlow. (They are not mention my issue).

Comment: Generate new api key based on your IDE SHA1 and paste it to your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `API-KEY` authentication issue.

You need to get your SHA1 for this pc and put it in your `Google developer console`project. Or re-generate a new API key.

For more details, how to do it, please refer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSPjWpLPFEfOCbezi6vATIh&index=25).